# PHP-FPM CPU usage very high

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, elasticsearch, php-fpm

I am using magento 2.4.3-p2 running php-7.4-fpm and nginx 1.18 on ubuntu 20.04 with elasticsearch 7.17.6 and varnish 6.2.1. My server has 32GB RAM and Intel Xeon-E2136 processor.

Everything has been working great with a very low load average (around 0.2) when the site has low traffic, but yesterday i upgraded to magento 2.4.3-p3 and things immediately when downhill. The load average went up to 5+ and stayed there until i realised 24 hours later. PHP-FM is running 4 processes all with 100% CPU which is causing this. RAM usage is around what it always is at between 16-18GB (this is due to elasticsearch).
When this CPU goes above 5.15 it seems to make varnish fall and i get an error 503 varnish backend fail.
I have rebooted my server, made sure everything is up to date, but the the PHP-FPM usage soon goes back up. Restarting PHP does the same.

I have now downgraded back to 2.4.3-p2 but im still having the same issue, but in theory everything is the same as it was yesterday now, short of restoring the file and database backup.

Is there a way to find out what PHP-FPM processes are doing so i can troubleshoot this issue. Varnish and nginx logs dont seem to give me any useful information.
I've changed the timeout in the default.vcl for varnish to 5s instead of 2s which gives me a bit longer under high CPU load, but i'd like to figure out what is causing this as its not sustainable to run a web server at 50% load when the site has no visitors.

`php-fpm: pool www` is the line when viewing htop which 4 php-fpm processes the majority of the time all at 100% or very close to.
I think i have narrowed this down to an elasticsearch issue, but not sure how to solve it. Restarting elasticsearch has not helped

Output of `ps -ax | grep php`

````
  16634 ?        Ss     0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
  16644 ?        S     11:09 php-fpm: pool www
  16645 ?        R     22:07 php-fpm: pool www
  16646 ?        S     25:06 php-fpm: pool www
  16647 ?        S     27:18 php-fpm: pool www
  16648 ?        R     22:05 php-fpm: pool www
  16649 ?        R     43:58 php-fpm: pool www
  16691 ?        S     22:15 php-fpm: pool www
  16765 ?        R     51:00 php-fpm: pool www
  16819 ?        R     60:00 php-fpm: pool www
  17451 ?        R     30:33 php-fpm: pool www
  17628 ?        R     35:29 php-fpm: pool www
  18082 ?        S      9:36 php-fpm: pool www
  18928 ?        R      1:59 php-fpm: pool www
  19234 ?        R      3:38 php-fpm: pool www
  19714 ?        R     26:53 php-fpm: pool www
  20430 ?        R     10:37 php-fpm: pool www
  20919 ?        S      1:26 php-fpm: pool www
  21121 ?        S      0:19 php-fpm: pool www
  21156 ?        R     12:24 php-fpm: pool www
  21164 ?        R      5:11 php-fpm: pool www
  21223 ?        S      1:49 php-fpm: pool www
  21230 ?        R     15:06 php-fpm: pool www
  21270 ?        S      3:28 php-fpm: pool www
  23831 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php7.4 /var/www/mysite.com/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/mysite.com/var/log/magento.cron.log
  23859 ?        S      0:01 /usr/bin/php7.4 /var/www/mysite.com/bin/magento queue:consumers:start inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus --single-thread --max-messages=10000
  24493 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto php```
````

Comment: Please check if cache is enabled after upgrade

Comment: 'ps -ax | grep php' will list out the php processes running. It's probably either cron or indexing you're experiencing.

Comment: I've added the output of that command to my post. My load average is currently running at 13 now.   
Cache is enabled

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables; B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) STATUS; not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS; G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.